# Unable to execute fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and not updating csv file

Tags: php, csv

```
// First, prepare the statement, using placeholders
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo "Hi";
// Export every row to a file
fputcsv($data, $row);
}
```

Is this correct way to do and if yes than why do I get false value for var_dump and than it does not go into while loop and does not write into csv file.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump(error_get_last()) after you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is missing is that you first need to open the csv file:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
```

then you can put data into it:

```
fputcsv($fp, $data);
```

As for the var_dump printing out false, you would have to provide more information about what objects you are actually using I think. (ie: what is $this->connection ?)

I don't know if this will help, but try to do it without the $this->connection:

```
$config['database'] = 'sakila';
$config['host'] = 'localhost';
$config['username'] = 'root';
$config['password'] = '';

$d = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$config['database'].';host='.$config['host'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM actor";
$stmt = $d->prepare($query);

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$data = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Hi";
    // Export every row to a file
    fputcsv($data, $row);
}
```

Comment: I am calling this function from another class's function and therein am opening the file and than am passing data stream back to this function and then doing the process further. I am not sure as to why this is happening.

Comment: Basically `$this->connection` points to an underlying PDO connection which is present in another Dao class which am using in my this class.

Comment: Maybe you are not connected to the database and it is failing silently?

Comment: Not it is connected as am using different function and for them it is connected.

Comment: Well... you could always var_dump($this->connection->errorInfo()) to see what all is in there, it might give you some idea of why it isn't working (var_dump($this->connection) probably won't help too much as PDO hides it's contents from that)).

Comment: It gives me array with Null element in it signifying that there is no errors occured. Not sure as to why it is not working though.

Comment: @SeanJA: It worked now, probably there is some issue with pdo connection, also currently using this am just able to get content of the database, is there anyway wherein I can get header information for the database inside the CSV file ?

Comment: Do you mean the names of the columns of the table? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Comment: How can I get column names into csv file, currently am only getting data present in the database into the csv file.

Comment: You have to do two selects for that, first do the show columns (or select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='my_table'; ) one, then do the second select. Since column names rarely change, you could also hard code them in your php code instead (and update them as needed).